# Finding the infamous " ' "

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

I'm just starting to teach myself SQL using postgresql and psequel using the book "Head First SQL". I'm trying to add values to my first table like so:

```
insert into my_contacts 

(last_name,
first_name, 
email, 
gender,
birthday,
profession,
location,
status,
interests,
seeking)
values 
(‘Anderson’, 
‘Jillian’, 
‘jill_anderson@breakneckpizza.com’, 
‘f’, 
‘1980-09-05’, 
‘technical writer’, 
‘Palo Alto, CA’, 
‘Single’, 
‘Kayaking, Reptiles’, 
‘Relationship, Friends’);
```

but I keep getting a message saying there is a syntax error on or near the " ' ". There are about a million of those which makes narrowing down which one very difficult, but I've been through every single simple quote on this list and I can't figure out what's going wrong. When I try entering this straight into the terminal I get a message saying

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "’"
LINE 17: ‘1980-09-05’,
```

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with the date? Am I using too many simple quotes?

Thanks!
                    ^

Comment: What is the datatype of the birthday field? If it's a date, '1980-09-05' is probably not a valid way to express a date in postgreSQL and  you need to do something like `to_date('1980/09/05', 'YYYY/MM/DD')`. I don't know postgreSQL at all but hopefully that works.

Comment: All your quotes looks like smart quotes rather than just `'`.

Answer (score 5):

As Gordon said in the comments, those are not single quote characters (the one you typed in this question title is). They are [curly quotes](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) which are two different character codes which SQL parsers will not recognize. They might as well be sad emoji surrounding your values.

Which text editor are you using? You may be typing single quotes but your editor is attempting to be (un)helpful by converting them (it's hard to type them on purpose). You can look to see if you can disable smart quotes in the settings...or try a more code centric editor.

Try this version of your query:

```
insert into my_contacts
(last_name,
first_name,
email,
gender,
birthday,
profession,
location,
status,
interests,
seeking)
values
('Anderson',
'Jillian',
'jill_anderson@breakneckpizza.com',
'f',
'1980-09-05',
'technical writer',
'Palo Alto, CA',
'Single',
'Kayaking, Reptiles',
'Relationship, Friends');
```

Comment: I'm using Pages on Mac to type commands out before I enter them. I'm sorry, but I can't visually tell the difference between the single quote that I used and the single quote that you used. I only have one single quote button my keyboard which looks like this ' , and attempting to create a curly quote only yields this: æ.

Comment: You are using the correct button. Pages is converting them automatically for you, which you do not want. Here are instructions that should help: http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks. If that doesn't work try the plain TextEdit app.

Comment: Actually, for Pages under the Edit menu select Substitutions and uncheck the 'Smart Quotes' item. Also, if you take a sample of your code and increase the font size a bunch, you should be able to see the difference in the quotes.